How to redirect non-www to www under these conditions on apache?
References
apache redirect from non www to www
Problem
I am attempting to redirect non-www requests to www requests. I tried the code commented below but it doesnt work. I also tried the codes in the reference above and still nothing.
What am I doing wrong?
CODE
# ModRewrite must be active on Apache
RewriteEngine On

#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.html

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"

#Redirect non-www to www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.br [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]

# First check if domain starts with www. and add it
# then if not using SSL force it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# Redirect all trafic to SpringBoot server.
# It must be running and, in this case, listening to port 10094
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:10094/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:10094/$1 [P,L]



# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php83” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php83 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

